# How can i do shorten my code with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
 <div class="logo-contentBlock"> 
   <a href="#logo-first-content" class="content-page-scroll-1">BLOG</a>
 </div>

 <div id="#logo-first-content"></div>




    $(".content-page-scroll-1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#content-first-content').offset().top - 60
        },5000);
    });
    $(".content-page-scroll-2").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#content-second-content').offset().top - 60
        }, 5000);
    });
    $(".content-page-scroll-3").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#logo-thirt-content').offset().top - 60
        }, 5000);
    });
```

I have about 9 codes like this way. How can I shorten them? Clicking buttons, they all go to different div.

Answer (score 3):

This will be my purposed solution for the above problem.

```
<div class="content-page-scroll" data-id="content-first-content"></div>
<div class="content-page-scroll" data-id="content-second-content"></div>
<div class="content-page-scroll" data-id="content-third-content"></div>
            .
            .
            .
<div class="content-page-scroll" data-id="content-n-content"></div>
```

Here the JS code for the click event.

```
$(".content-page-scroll").click(function () {
$thisDataId = $(this).data('id');
$('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(`#${$thisDataId}`).offset().top - 60
     }, 5000);
});
```

In this way, you sum up this problem with a single JS click event.
Hopefully it may help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: Its working but only second-content and last content. I gave div's id to 'a' tag. I just want scrolltop top - 60  when ı click a tag and scroll div

Comment: For this scenario, you can do this in this way.

$("div a.content-page-scroll").click(function () {
$thisDataId = $(this).data('href');
$('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(`.#${$thisDataId}`).offset().top - 60
     }, 5000);
});

Comment: I will.  Im using grunt ı did your solution but "message: 'Unexpected character \'`\'', "

Comment: @Emre Update this code $(`#${$thisDataId}`) to $(".#" + $thisDataId). Now you wont get that above error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a function like this:

```js
function createScrollClick(elem, location) {
    $(elem).click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(location).offset().top - 60
        },5000);
    });
}
```

Then either call it the nine times you need to call it for each click you want to set up:

`createScrollClick('.content-page-scroll-1', '#content-first-content'')`, etc.

...or you could put all of those values in an array or object and loop through those values calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

In php:

```
<script>
<?php
for ($x=1; $x<9; $x++){
echo '$(".content-page-scroll-'.$x.'").click(function() {
        $(\'html, body\').animate({
            scrollTop: $(\'#content-'.$x.'-content\').offset().top - 60
        },5000);
    });';
}
?>
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't shorten the javascript at all.  And where did OP say they were using PHP?  Might be `[asp.net-mvc]`.  *and* you can't server-side .js files, so if OP is nicely separating his running code from his markup (as we all should) then this won't work then either.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.